# L'utilizzo di "orco" come interiezione è usuale in qualche zona d'Italia?

Tags: word-usage

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> GIOVANNI     Le manette? Perché, scusi? 
>   BRIGADIERE     Per offesa e insulti a pubblico ufficiale. 
>   GIOVANNI     Ma che insulti! Mica le ho dette io quelle cose lì, le ha dette poco fa un suo collega della PS... È lui che
>   ha detto che voi vi sentite come gli sbirri del potere, servi del padrone! 
>   BRIGADIERE     Voi chi? Noi carabinieri? 
>   GIOVANNI     No, lui diceva voi… nel senso di loro... loro...
>   della PS. 
>   BRIGADIERE     Ah beh, se si sentono servi loro della PS, è un
>   altro discorso. Togligli le manette. Ma attento a come
>   parla!
>   GIOVANNI     Sì, sì, sto attento... (*A parte*) **Orco**, come sono
>   separati ’sti corpi separati!

Questa esclamazione, "orco", mi è sembrata divertente e mi ha incuriosita perché non ricordo di averla mai letta o sentita. Mi sono subito chiesta: si usa veramente in Italia o si tratta invece di un'invenzione dell'autore? Ho cercato alla voce "orco" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione di questo vocabolo come esclamazione.

Ricercando con Google, ho trovato [questo forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/urca.782353/) in cui si afferma che si usa (o si usava) nell'area intorno a Milano, ma ho trovato anche questi esempi di uso di "orco" come interiezione sul [*Vocabolario di Fiorentino Contemporaneo*](http://www.vocabolariofiorentino.it/lemma/po-/2441) dell'Accademia della Crusca:

> Io, pe modo di dire, son superstizioso a i’ massimo. ’**Orco** cane, un po’ di più! // Allora, quando si dà a uno di beccarone, è perché c’ha la mamma trò... la moglie troia. ’**Orco** diavolo! Un po’ di più!

Quindi, devo capire da questi esempi che l'utilizzo di "orco" come esclamazione è comune in Toscana? Si tratta di un uso regionale? È anche usuale in altre regioni d'Italia?

Comment: È un modo per evitare di dire “porco”; “cane” o “diavolo” stanno al posto di un nome che non si dovrebbe pronunciare invano.

Comment: @egreg: Quindi, si tratta di un eufemismo? E l'apostrofo che appare nel *Vocabolario di Fiorentino Contemporaneo* rappresenta forse la "p" soppressa?

Comment: Questo [libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=-aZBAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT36&lpg=PT36&dq=orco+eufemismo+porco&source=bl&ots=EcNwYwWeoP&sig=ACfU3U0KbcwFAJi-Y_gP4huuM4C2TXX4og&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVkL2As8fmAhVlA2MBHZyyAV4Q6AEwBnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=orco%20eufemismo%20porco&f=false) conferma quanto ha detto @egreg.

Comment: In Veneto posso certificare.

Comment: Grazie, @SteakOverflow, e benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una comune bestemmia (in Italia si sentono spesso) adopera la parola *porco*. Il nome proprio viene spesso sostituito in modo da evitare, in modo piuttosto ipocrita, di pronunciare la bestemmia; si sente spesso *cane* (fusione con l'altra bestemmia più comune), *diavolo* o *zio*. Molti nemmeno sanno l'origine di *porco cane* e l'adoperano senza pensarci troppo.

Non sono sicuro che si configuri come [“eufemismo”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/eufemismo/). Per maggiore cautela, *porco* viene contratto in *orco*, che talvolta diventa esclamazione a sé stante, come nel brano di Fo. Si trova in alcuni testi *orcozio* oppure *orcozzio*.

Stefano Bartezzaghi ne tratta [qui](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0wdAQAAIAAJ&q=orcozio&dq=orcozio&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6gYy508fmAhX0RBUIHWiSDIAQ6AEIazAI), insieme ad altri eufemismi come *ostrega* e tutte le esclamazioni tipicamente toscane riguardanti la Maremma che, ovviamente, sostituisce una figura della religione cattolica.

Comment: Quindi, se ho capito bene, non è di uso regionale, vero?

Comment: @Charo Direi di no; non ho statistiche, ma lo si sente un po' ovunque.

Comment: @Charo Confermo anch'io di averlo sentito in varie parti d'Italia. Una probabile variante, di stampo fumettistico è _orpo_, usata come esclamazione a se stante.